# C# - Update button not updating

Tags: c#, sql, database

**C# - Update button not updating**

As mentioned. When the Update button is clicked after changes are made it reloads the page but does not update into the SQLDB. I'm just getting into programming and would like a little assistance.

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BiodiversityProject"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        //See above comments
        string image_folder = Server.MapPath("~\\uploadedimages\\");
        string dbfilename1 = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text.ToString();
        string dbfilename2 = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text.ToString();

        if (VideoFileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            string filename1 = VideoFileUpload.FileName.ToString();
            VideoFileUpload.SaveAs(image_folder + filename1);
            dbfilename1 = filename1;
        }

        string multimedia_folder = Server.MapPath("~\\uploaded_multimedia\\");

        if (VideoFileUpload.HasFile)
        {
            string filename2 = VideoFileUpload.FileName.ToString();
            VideoFileUpload.SaveAs(multimedia_folder + filename2);
            dbfilename2 = filename2;
        }
        //string connectionString = null;
        //int userId = 0;

        SqlCommand UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE LeagueTable SET BirdName = @p1, Quantity = @p2, Place = @p3, Location =@p4, Image = @p5, mediaclip =  @p6, Username = @p7, datetime = @p8, Active Status= @p9 WHERE Bird_ID = " + GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());

        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p1", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox1.Text.ToString();
        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p2", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = TextBox2.Text.ToString();
        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p3", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString();
        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p4", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = txtlocation.Text.ToString();
        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p5", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = dbfilename1.ToString();
        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p6", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = dbfilename2.ToString();
        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p7", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = User.Identity.Name;
        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p8", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString().ToString();
        UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@p9", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            UpdateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: firstly WHERE Bird_ID = " + GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString()); make a parameterize
WHERE Bird_ID = @PAR_BIRDID  and add new parameters
 UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PAR_BIRDID", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar)).Value =  GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString();
what is error   ?

Comment: likely an exception is happening and your empty catch is hiding it. You should also move conn.Close() to a finally { }

Comment: catch (Exception ex)
    {
   messageBox.Show(ex.message);
    }

Comment: My system does not allow me to input messageBox.Show into the catch. This is for a WebApp.

Comment: Also, I the system is not displaying an error, just looping the page.

Comment: Usually these are occur because you are writing to the wrong database.  Check you connection string to make sure it is really saving the file to the server.  You shouldn't use the mdb filename in the connection string instead use the database name and the server.

Comment: You are setting your parameters as "varchar" - are your columns really all varchar columns? I would expect `quantity` to be numeric and `datetime` to be a date.

Comment: As mentioned, do `catch(Exception ex)` then put a break point in the catch block and look at the exception.

Comment: BTW why using parameters everywhere but `WHERE Bird_ID = " + GridView1.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString()` ?

Comment: You have open connection two times "conn.Open();"